Problem with understanding the proof using a reflection in the plane
I'm trying to understand the proof of following statement: The point M belongs to the diameter $\overline{AB}$ of the given circle. The chord $\overline{CD}$ passes through the point M and forms an angle of 45° with AB. Then the sum $||^2+||^2$ does not depend on the position of the point M.
The idea is to use reflection, so wo obtain point $C'$ as an image of $C$ with respect to reflection to $AB.$ Then triangle $C'MD$ is right triangle with $|C'M|=|CM|$ and $|'|^2+||^2$ is the square of length of hypotenuse $\overline{C'D}.$ Explanation then goes: Since $\measuredangle C'CD=45°$, the length of $\overline{C'D}$ does not change by moving $M$ along $\overline{AB}.$
Can someone please explain, why because of this angle of $45°$, the length of $\overline{C'D}$ won't change?

Inscribed angle theorem?

Not sure, I see that inscribed angle won't change by moving point M, but if it is some other angle than 45°, the length would change.

I see now, thank you. Since $\angle C'CD=45°,$ the central angle is a right angle and C'SD is always right angle with hypotenuse $\overline{C'D}$.
